# How can I force outstanding samples lingering on an IWMSinkWriter to be written?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I have an `IWMSinkWriter` object that is receiving compressed samples from a WMA encoder transform.

I want to perform a "Drain" operation in which the input samples still lingering on the sink writer are not dropped (as it currently happens with the `IWMSinkWriter::Flush()` operation) but instead are committed to disk without closing the destination file, something akin to calling `fflush()` on a C file).

I thought that the samples that I passed to the `IWMSinkWriter` would eventually be written to disk so I tried implementing this "Drain" functionallity like this:

```
void WmaWriterBox::HandleCommand(DrainCommand^ command) {
   HRESULT hRes;
   BASE::HandleCommand(command);
   MF_SINK_WRITER_STATISTICS statistics;
   statistics.cb = sizeof(statistics);
   // spin-wait until the pending samples are processed
   while( true ) {
      COM_CALL(_pWriter->GetStatistics(0, &statistics));
      if( !statistics.dwNumOutstandingSinkSampleRequests )
         break;
      Thread::Sleep(10);
   }
}
```

Unfortunately the outstanding sample count never drops to zero so I enter an infinite loop.

**Is there a way in which I can accomplish this "write-pending-data-to-disk"  functionality?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use [`IMFSinkWriter::Finalize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374648):

> Call this method after you send all of the input samples to the sink writer. The method performs any operations needed to create the final output from the media sink.

The method enqueues end-of-stream commands internally and starts completing the output. The pending samples are expected to be included.

Unlike MFTs, file writing is not supposed to implement draining in terms of producing as much of output stream as possible, then getting back prepared to accept further input. Most file formats are structured in the way that the files are not readable before completely finalized, and potential draining will not ensure the currently fed data is written into file and the file is readable. In most cases you are responsible to finalize writing before any written data is playable back.

Hence, you don't have a method or even challenge to deal with outstanding data: you just keep writing it and finalize in the end. The sink is writing in some respectively convenient way and it's only contract responsibility is to deliver good output file once you are completely done with writing. Note that with ASF format specifically the requirements are somewhat relaxed and the files might be - to some extent - still readable if not finalized correctly.

Flushing, on the contrary, discards undone data:

> For each stream that is flushed, the sink writer drops all pending samples...

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for your response, actually I don't want to close the output file as such, I just want to make sure that samples that have been received by the sink are actually written to disk and not kept in memory. This is really for consistency, as our DSP mini framework components support both Drain and Flush operations (in the same sense as the MF transforms do), so it would be nice if I could implement the Drain operation on the WMA writer component.

Comment: Even though drain on an MFT might result in availability of the MFT for further input after drain in complete, it is not the case with file writing. There is no draining. There is also no much of practical use in making sure samples in transit are processed because it does not guarantee that data is *actually* in the file and the file remains readable. Even though it might be the case with ASF. Before MP4 is finalized it is typically unreadable anyway, even if drain function was there.

Comment: Thanks Roman, if you post your last comment as an answer I will gladly accept it.